# GET - get the value and append to a link?

Tags: php

I have a query string in the URL:

```
?search=whatever
```

I need to append this to paginated links:

```
example.com/articles/p3/?search=whatever
```

I can get the value using:

```
$_GET['search'] //whatever
```

But what's the best way to build the string so I can append to my URL. Is there a proper way or would it just be a case of appending a string:

```
'?search='.$_GET['search']
```

Comment: It would just be a case of appending a string to your url. (Hello again by the way.)

Comment: You could use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` instead of each argument alone.

Comment: Well if you don't mind using clean URL for your search too (which is of few interest in most cases) your last solution will do the trick. You might want to do this by looping through your GET variables though or using the full querystring variable as suggested by scragar, else if you wish to add more parameters (like order for example), you'll need to add more code while a loop would make it more generic.

Comment: @scragar the server query string gives me an ampersand rather than a question mark in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

For building url's you always should use propper urlBuilder.

For PHP you can use [parse-url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [http-build-query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Answer (score 0):

If it's only one variable you are going to use on that page it is ok to use

```
'?search='.$_GET['search']
```

But you should also make sure that you care for encoding that var with [urlencode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) somewhere in your code (where the var is initially set up).

If you want to build an URL with multiple args there is a nice little function called [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.http-build-query.php) which can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just do

```
 $search = $_GET['search'];
 $pagecount = 10; //Count of results from DB or similar pagination data. ie skip take etc..


for(i=0;i<$pagecount;i++){
  echo "<a href='getmoreresults.php?search=".$search."&page=".$i."'>$i</a>";
}
```